# Couldn't match types deep in a monad stack

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'm writing a OpenGL program for learning purposes, using `GPipe` library. The library does some black type magic, and that (with a `newtype` from me thrown in for a good measure) makes me unable to properly parse error messages. The following code doesn't compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Except

import qualified "GPipe" Graphics.GPipe as GP
import qualified "GPipe-GLFW" Graphics.GPipe.Context.GLFW as GLFW

---- types ----

newtype Processor ctx os a = Processor {
    runProcessor :: GP.ContextT ctx os (StateT (FullState os) IO) a
}

data Transition os = ToMainMenu (FullState os)
                   | Quit

type CType = GP.RGBFloat
type UnitWindow os = GP.Window os CType ()

data ArtState os = ArtState {
    _asWindow :: UnitWindow os
}

data ProgState = ProgState

data FullState os = FullState {
    _fsArtState :: ArtState os
  , _fsProgState :: ProgState
}

---- constructors ----

mkFullState :: UnitWindow os -> FilePath -> ExceptT String IO (FullState os)
mkFullState window directory = do
    art <- mkArtState window directory
    prog <- mkProgState directory
    return FullState {
        _fsArtState = art
      , _fsProgState = prog
    }

mkArtState :: UnitWindow os -> FilePath -> ExceptT String IO (ArtState os)
mkArtState window _ = return ArtState {
    _asWindow = window
}

mkProgState :: FilePath -> ExceptT String IO ProgState
mkProgState _ = return ProgState

---- processors ----

start :: Processor ctx os (Transition os)
start = Processor $ GP.runContextT GLFW.defaultHandleConfig $ do
    win <- GP.newWindow (GP.WindowFormatColor GP.RGB8) (GLFW.defaultWindowConfig "Foobar")
    possiblyState <- liftIO $ runExceptT $ mkFullState win "./"
    case possiblyState of
         Left err -> liftIO $ putStrLn err >> return Quit
         Right state -> return $ ToMainMenu state

---- Main ----

main :: IO ()
main = do
    transition <- runProcessor start
    case transition of 
         Quit -> return ()
         ToMainMenu _ -> return ()
```

The idea is to have `Processor`s return a `Transition` to be used by the main loop to select an appropriate path of execution. The compilation error is as follows:

```
/tmp/testing/app/Main.hs:60:25: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘os1’ with ‘os’
      ‘os1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall os1.
          GP.ContextT
            GLFW.Handle
            os1
            (GP.ContextT ctx os (StateT (FullState os) IO))
            (Transition os)
        at app/Main.hs:(55,21)-(60,49)
      ‘os’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          start :: forall ctx os. Processor ctx os (Transition os)
        at app/Main.hs:54:1-41
      Expected type: GP.ContextT
                       GLFW.Handle
                       os1
                       (GP.ContextT ctx os (StateT (FullState os) IO))
                       (Transition os)
        Actual type: GP.ContextT
                       GLFW.Handle
                       os1
                       (GP.ContextT ctx os (StateT (FullState os) IO))
                       (Transition os1)
    • In the expression: return $ ToMainMenu state
      In a case alternative: Right state -> return $ ToMainMenu state
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        case possiblyState of
          Left err -> liftIO $ putStrLn err >> return Quit
          Right state -> return $ ToMainMenu state
    • Relevant bindings include
        state :: FullState os1 (bound at app/Main.hs:60:16)
        possiblyState :: Either String (FullState os1)
          (bound at app/Main.hs:57:5)
        win :: GP.Window os1 GP.RGBFloat () (bound at app/Main.hs:56:5)
        start :: Processor ctx os (Transition os)
          (bound at app/Main.hs:55:1)
   |
60 |          Right state -> return $ ToMainMenu state
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My understanding of Haskell and monads doesn't allow me to fix this, I can sort of see that `os1` and `os` are produced by different equations and therefore GHC can't just mark them as same, but I'm at a loss as to how to repair that. If I remove `os` parameter from the `Transition` enum, the error disappears, but I *need* it to pass the state around instead of reinitializing it in every Processor.

Could someone explain what's going wrong and how to fix it?

PS. Oh, and when I clumped all the code in a single file, a new error appeared that was previously masked by compilation order.

Comment: Is it intentional that there are two `GP.ContextT` transformers at the location of this error message? Why are you calling `GP.runContextT` there, and what if you try to remove it?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia It is not intentional and puzzles me greatly. If I remove it I get `Couldn't match expected type ‘GP.WindowParameters ctx’
                  with actual type ‘GLFW.WindowConfig’
    • In the second argument of ‘GP.newWindow’Couldn't match expected type ‘GP.WindowParameters ctx’
                  with actual type ‘GLFW.WindowConfig’
    • In the second argument of ‘GP.newWindow’`. Formatting on this is probably going to be horribly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function that returns a `ContextT` value (here wrapped in `Processor`), like `start`, should not call [`GP.runContextT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GPipe-2.2.3/docs/Graphics-GPipe-Context.html#t:ContextT).

`GP.runContextT` is used to initialize and provide the context to execute the processors, which you only want to do once at the start of the whole program. Thus, it should probably be in `main`, together with `newWindow`, `defaultWindowConfig` and `mkFullState`.

A `Processor` like `start` can get the current state using the `StateT` transformer. But first, we must fix the `Processor` type. Notice the type of `runContextT`, in particular the `forall`:

```
runContextT
    :: (MonadIO m, MonadAsyncException m, ContextHandler ctx)
    => ContextHandlerParameters ctx -> (forall os. ContextT ctx os m a) -> m a
```

This `forall` imposes that the type variable `os` can not occur in `m` or in `a`, preventing certain resources from leaking. This is incompatible with the current definition of `Processor`, since `StateT (FullState os) IO` contains `os`. You can probably swap the transformers.

```
newtype Processor ctx os a = Processor {
    runProcessor :: StateT (FullState os) (GP.ContextT ctx os IO) a
}
```

Now `start` can use `get` to access the current state, and since it is not supposed to handle initialization, it doesn't have the `Quit` branch anymore (you might no longer want to make `start` a `Processor` at this point, but hopefully this is close enough to what you'd actually like to do with other processors):

```
start :: Processor ctx os (Transition os)
start = Processor $ do
  s <- get
  return $ ToMainMenu s
```

And `main` can look like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
    -- Initialize and provide context, i.e, convert the wrapped
    -- do-block of type `ContextT _ _ IO` to `IO`
    GP.runContextT GLFW.defaultHandleConfig $ do

        -- Create a GLFW window
        -- You can probably create more than one
        win <- GP.newWindow (GP.WindowFormatColor GP.RGB8) (GLFW.defaultWindowConfig "Foobar")

        -- Create the initial processor state, handling initialization failures
        s_ <- liftIO $ runExceptT $ mkFullState win "./"
        s0 <- case s_ of
            Left e -> fail e
            Right s0 -> return s0

        -- Run a processor
        (transition, s1) <- (`runStateT` s0) $ runProcessor start

        case transition of
            Quit -> return ()
            ToMainMenu _ -> return ()
```